# Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: contract-development, ether

thanks all of guys help me. thanks very much.
I created contract in rinkeby test network. the contract address is:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x5dedcba9851e5c7ff464d5ee6ef75301a8c43d8b

I try to write code run contract transfrom method for move ERC2.0 token from A address to B address. but is always stop and show error message:Transaction has been reverted by the EVM.  I am not sure what's trouble. hope someone help me.

```
fs = require("fs");
Web3 = require('web3');
url = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/29129372289d49dca8ecec82d0aa8e7a";
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url));
var contractAddress ="0x5DedCBa9851E5C7FF464D5Ee6Ef75301a8c43d8b";
var abiArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('kct.json', 'utf-8'));
abi = JSON.parse(abiArray.result);
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);

web3.eth.getBlock("latest",function(err,block){
const gasLimit = block.gasLimit;
console.log('gas limit:',gasLimit);
prkey="0xDE9EAD9D7DE97A3F94D66F9D8D7BF437AA76A28D4A13202B446D48AB1979DBDB";
data = contract.methods.transferFrom("0x410E6a1be27424091ABb15aA096D492958fD55f1","0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732","12").encodeABI();
console.log("data",data);

    console.log('gasPrice:',gasPrice);

    console.log("contractAddress",contractAddress);
    var tx = {
    from:"0x410E6a1be27424091ABb15aA096D492958fD55f1",
    to:contractAddress,
    data:data,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(4200000000),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(4300000),
    };
    web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx,prkey).then(tx => {
            console.log('Result++: ', tx);
            var raw = tx.rawTransaction;
            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw).on('receipt', res => {
                    console.log('操作成功');
            }).on('error', err => {
                    console.log(err);
            });
    }).then(receipt => console.log("Transaction succeeded", receipt)).catch(error => console.error(error))
})
```

Comment: usually this kind of errors is not meeting `revert` , `assert` or `require` conditions, so you must check what input are you giving to your contract, and you should post the method's source code if you want someone to help you.

Comment: you have 3 `require`s there in `transfer()` method, some of them fails, post also the transaction hash, so we can check what input did you send to the contract

Comment: and the most likely, it is that you don't have the balance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `transferFrom()`, which is a way for address **A** to transfer tokens from address **B** to address **C**. In order to do that, address **B** must first authorize address **A** to do that by calling `approve()`.

But it looks like you're just trying to transfer from your own account, so you should just use `transfer()`:

```
data = contract.methods.transfer("0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732", "12").encodeABI();
```

Comment: thanks smarx!   it is run right. I need read more code, need know more about contract code.